# In Pandas, how to apply 2 custom formulas in a groupby.agg() method?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, dataframe

I have this df:

```
 A = pd.DataFrame([['Big', -2, 4, 1, 0], ['Medium', 4, 4, -1, -1], ['Big', 3, -3, -2, -1], ['Small', 0, -1, -3, 5], ['Small', 1, 4, -2, 5]],
             columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I want to group by A, and make calculations ('mean', 'std', and two custom) on the other columns. The custom functions are just counting the elements that are >= 0, and also the elements that are < 0. This would be the output:

```
                                         A
                Big                   Medium                   Small
       mean   std   Up   Down    mean  std   Up   Down    mean   std   Up   Down
B      0.50  3.53    1   1         4   Nan     1     0     0.50  0.70    2     0
C      0.50  4.94    1   1         4   Nan     1     0     1.50  3.53    1     1
D     -0.50  2.12    1   1        -1   Nan     0     1    -2.50  0.70    0     2
E     -0.25  0.70    1   1        -1   Nan     0     1     5.00  0.0     2     0
```

Note: The display doesn't have to be in this shape, the important thing is that it contains all the information I need.

So far I got this

```
f = ['mean', 'std']
A.groupby(A['A']).agg(f)

           B               C               D               E          
        mean       std  mean       std  mean       std  mean       std
A                                                                     
Big      0.5  3.535534   0.5  4.949747  -0.5  2.121320  -0.5  0.707107
Medium   4.0       NaN   4.0       NaN  -1.0       NaN  -1.0       NaN
Small    0.5  0.707107   1.5  3.535534  -2.5  0.707107   5.0  0.000000
```

I'm stuck with the other two functions, I tried doing custom formulas

```
function = ['mean', 'std', (lambda x: x >= 0).sum(), (lambda y: y < 0).sum()]
```

But I get:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

Thanks

Comment: It works for me; can you show me more exactly what you're doing to get that error? What pandas version?

Comment: function = ['mean', 'std', (lambda x: x >= 0).sum(), (lambda y: y < 0).sum()]. Then I get AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sum'. Can you show me what is the function that worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [17]: def up(x):
    return (x>=0).sum()
   ....: 

In [18]: def down(x):
    return (x<0).sum()
   ....: 

In [19]: f = ['mean', 'std', up, down]

In [20]: A.groupby(A['A']).agg(f)
Out[20]: 
           B                         C                         D            \
        mean       std  up  down  mean       std  up  down  mean       std   
A                                                                            
Big      0.5  3.535534   1     1   0.5  4.949747   1     1  -0.5  2.121320   
Medium   4.0       NaN   1     0   4.0       NaN   1     0  -1.0       NaN   
Small    0.5  0.707107   2     0   1.5  3.535534   1     1  -2.5  0.707107   

                     E                      
        up  down  mean       std  up  down  
A                                           
Big      1     1  -0.5  0.707107   1     1  
Medium   0     1  -1.0       NaN   0     1  
Small    0     2   5.0  0.000000   2     0
```

You have two problems:

First, you're putting the parenthesis in the wrong place here: `(lambda x: x >= 0).sum()` should be `lambda x: (x >= 0).sum()`.

The second one is that pandas is trying to figure out the name of the columns for the `agg()` from the names of the aggregation functions, so if you try to pass in two lambda functions to agg(), you'll get an error. Defining them as functions solves this (as I have above).